# Class Property method not read/called - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add a class property method to the Game model, however it is not appearing on the frontend when I call game.owner_username.

Model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    players = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    kickoff_time = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    max_player_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    goal_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="games", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    @property
    def owner_username(self):
        return self.owner.username
```

EDIT:

Fixed by adding this line of code to serializer:

```
owner_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
```

So now my serializer is:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# Serializers take the data which is on our server and convert it into a
# format which can be read by other technologies (in our case JSON).
# When data is sent TO the server it does the opposite, converting data
# into a format our server can handle.
owner_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

class Meta:
    model = Game
    fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: The owner field is nullable, does the game have an owner? Can you try putting just game.owner?

Comment: game.owner workers as expected; returns the owner pk attribute.

Comment: The pk? Is this about a DRF API? Can you share the serializer and view?

Comment: Just fixed, see edit if you care about solution.

Comment: seems the `GameSerializer` is fine, Still not resolved the issue?